# Migrating from Mysql to mariaDB killed website

Tags: mysql, wordpress, varnish, mariadb

followed this tutorial for for digital ocean droplet web server.

http://www.unixmen.com/10-easy-steps-to-upgrade-from-mysql-to-mariadb-on-centos-6-4/

which went smoothly untill rebooting now my sites are all white screening, here is a wordpress installation with the debug mode on.

http://grandmstramrod.co.uk/

the service is also running varnish cache.

any ideas would be great

thanks

Comment: http://www.remap-it.co.uk/

Comment: This is better asked on http://server-fault.com/  That being said, have you checked the three items on the WP whitescreen page? "Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
Are you sure that the database server is running?"